# How to run one of two codes when an Excel file is opened?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run code when an Excel file is opened.
If the file is opened from a particular path, a separate code should run.

Below is the code in the "thisworkbook" section of the xlam file.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

MsgBox "You just ran this code"

Application.Run "SaveFile.Savefile"

End Sub
```

Below is the code to run if the file is opened from a particular folder.

```vb
Sub SaveFile()

MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim filepath As String
filepath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
If filepath = "D:\OneDrive - R.N. Kothari & Associates\Email Attachments" Then
    MsgBox "we won"
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly, you just want an if statement that checks the file's current location. Easily done because excel saves every open workbook's path, accesible through `Workbooks("Name").Path` or `ThisWorkbook.Path`. So you just need to put this in the Workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If ThisWorkbook.Path = Path1 Then
        'Do Stuff
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Path = Path2 Then
        'Do Stuff
    Else
        'Do Stuff
    End If
End Sub
```